# How to define a method that takes a heterogeneous sequence of objects of types belonging to a certain typeclass?

Tags: scala, types, typeclass, shapeless

There is a type that can be parametrized by a certain restricted set of types:

```
trait Base[T] { def f(t: T): List[T] }
implicit object StringBase extends Base[String] {
  override def f(t: String) = t.toList.map(c => String.valueOf(c))
}
implicit object IntBase extends Base[Int] {
  override def f(t: Int) = List(t,t,t)
}
```

Now, I can define a function that takes a collection of a specific type and processes it:

```
def consume[T : Base](xs: Seq[T]) =
  xs.map(x => implicitly[Base[T]].f(x).mkString("-"))
```

How do I define a function that takes a sequence of objects for types of which there exists an implicit conversion to `Base` and do the same? In a type-safe way, of course.

If I was not entirely clear, here's what I'd like to have:

```
consume(Seq(1,"asd", 3)) // => Seq("1-1-1", "a-s-d", "3-3-3")
```

I'm sure I can achieve it with shapeless' `HList`, but what about core Scala? Anyway, putting `shapeless` tag in case functionally inclined guys are willing to help.

Comment: The problem is that the inferred type of the sequence will be the least-upper bound of the types of the elements (in this case `Any`). You can write it with `HList`, or you can do something awful with runtime reflection, but if you want core Scala _and_ type safety you're unfortunately out of luck.

Comment: @TravisBrown, that's what I was afraid of. I understand that it's a final answer to my problem, so maybe you should post it below so I could mark the question as closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist.Mapper
import ops.hlist.ToList

trait Base[T] { def f(t: T): List[T] }

implicit object StringBase extends Base[String] {
  override def f(t: String) = t.toList.map(c => String.valueOf(c))
}
implicit object IntBase extends Base[Int] {
  override def f(t: Int) = List(t,t,t)
}
object base extends Poly1 {
    implicit def forBase[A : Base] = at[A](x => implicitly[Base[A]].f(x))
}

def consume[T <: HList, Inter <: HList](xs: T)
(implicit
    mapBase: Mapper.Aux[base.type, T, Inter],
    interToList: ToList[Inter, List[Any]]): Seq[String] = {
    xs.map(base).toList.map(_.mkString("-"))
}
```

Two key parts:

1. `object base extends Poly1` : This is a polymorphic function only defined on types with a `Base` typeclass instance. It calls `Base.f` on its arg.
2. The implicits and type params in `consume` :

   - `T` is our input HList type. `Inter` is an intermediate type variable that is the output type of the result of mapping `base` over `T`.
   - `mapBase: Mapper.Aux[base.type, T, Inter]` : This is evidence that if we map `base` over `T` we get `Inter`. We need this to call `.map` on the incoming hlist. By putting it in our implicits list, we just require that it exists when the function is called. Shapeless will generate this for us if it can. If it can't, it most likely means that you forgot to define a `Base` instance for a type in `T`
   - `interToList: ToList[Inter, List[Any]]` : This is evidence that you can convert the HList `Inter` to a `List[List[Any]]`. So `List[Any]` must be the least-upperbound type of all the types in `Inter`. Once again, by putting it in the input implicits, we just require that shapeless can generate this for us. This is just boilerplate to prove to the compiler that we can call `toList` and get a `List[List[Any]]`. I haven't found a way to avoid this and the `Inter` variable in my experiences sadly.

Now thanks to all those implicits, we just call `xs.map(base)` to get an HList out with the appropriate `Base.f` applied. Then we call `.toList` to get a `List[List[Any]]`. Then we map over those `List[Any]`s and `mkString` with dashes as you wanted. And out comes our `Seq[String]`!

Here is it working in the REPL:

```
scala> consume(1 :: "asd" :: 3 :: HNil)
res0: Seq[String] = List(1-1-1, a-s-d, 3-3-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is dirty hack for consume method. Not super type safe and nice but may be fine as a workaround.

```
  trait Base[T] { def f(t: T): List[T] }
  implicit object StringBase extends Base[String] {
    override def f(t: String) = t.toList.map(c => String.valueOf(c))
  }
  implicit object IntBase extends Base[Int] {
    override def f(t: Int) = List(t,t,t)
  }

  case class Consumable[T](v: T, base: Base[T])

  implicit def toConsumable[T](v: T)(implicit base: Base[T], ev: ClassTag[T]) =
    Consumable(v, base)

  def consume(xs: Consumable[_]*) =
    xs.map(x => x.base.asInstanceOf[Base[Any]].f(x.v).mkString("-"))

  println(consume(1, 2, 3))
  println(consume("a", "b", "c"))
  println(consume(1, 2, "a", "b", "c"))
```